# Cannot translate date formats from rails form to mysql db

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple search form in rails 3 that has two date fields. I'm having a problem getting these dates into my mysql db.

I've tried using the [american_date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15538413/rails-change-date-format-before-saving-to-mysql-db) gem, specifying date formats in my initializers, in the config/locales/en.yml file, and directly on the date on the date fields themselves. Currently, I'm setting the rails-approved date format in the view -

```
<%= f.text_field :depart_date, :value=> Date.today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') %>
```

The dateformat in my DB is also YYYY-mm-dd, so things should be going smoothly.

The console tells me that the two date fields are both `class = "Date"`

I think I've found the disconnect. From the logs -

```
Started POST "/searches" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-30 17:43:26 -0400
Processing by SearchesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√","search"=>{"depart_date"=>"2013-10-30", 
"return_date"=>"2013-11-09"}
←[1m←[35m (0.0ms)←[0m  BEGIN
←[1m←[36mSQL (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mINSERT INTO `searches` (`depart_date`,`return_date`)
VALUES ('2013-30-10','2013-09-11')←[0m
←[1m←[35m (2.0ms)←[0m  COMMIT
```

Note that the month and day values are switched in the insert statement. How can I prevent this from happenening?

Comment: What happens when you use `<%= f.text_field :depart_date, :value=> Date.today %>`

Comment: Another option is trying `Date.today.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')`

Comment: The main thing is to let Rails do the translation for you, so use the minimal rails standard and go by examples in the api rather than mucking around with format I've learned from bitter experience.

Comment: Using `:value=> Date.today` shows the current date as "10/31/2013", but still tries to save it as `2013-31-10`. I tried `Date.today.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')`, but it does the same, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a virtual attribute to translate between the text field and Date in the db. You can follow the railscasts to get these working -

[#16 Virtual Attributes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes-revised)

[#32 Time in Text Field](http://railscasts.com/episodes/32-time-in-text-field)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your timezone is not set correctly. 
Check which timezone your MySQL is using and which one your Rails is using.

You can try forcing a timezone in your rails app like this

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
end
```

Comment: I set `config.time_Zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'`, and also tried once with `:local`, and confirmed that the db instance is using `SYSTEM` time. It's still not saving the dates properly, though.